# How to install Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu 14.04 using separate drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, windows-8.1

i have installed Ubuntu 14.04, but i've read many articles about issues when you've installed ubuntu first and windows afterwards. I have 2 separate SSD drives. On the first one i've installed Ubuntu, on the second one i plan to install Windows 8.

I can't turn off sata port of the first drive in a BIOS. Do i have to physically plug it out while installing windows?

I need windows just for gaming, so virtualization won't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're talking about is that when you install Windows it will overwrite the boot loader provided by the Linux installation.

There should be an option in your BIOS to switch the boot order of your SATA drives, then you can switch it back and add an entry in to you Linux bootloader for you Windows install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right.

normal way is:
`1 - install windows.`
`2 - install linux ( linux install bootloader automatically ).`

if you have a linux on a SSD and now want to install windows on the other SSD, this way can be good way i think:
`1 - you have installed linux.`
`2 - instaling windows8. ( this change your bootloader by default )`
`3 - install bootloader.`
simplest way for step 3 use `Super Grub Disk` or other ways like use `live-linux` to install bootloader.
when you install windos or linux i think they are set they address bootloader in MBR(master boot record) lastest bootloader set this address.

other amazing way is!
install a grub , find your SSD'UID (i think) and set your SSD address and other simple information ( can be found in a good geub istalled config file ) in the grub.
grub can be edited with `E` key.
good luck on this way :)!

other way:

`1 - you can install wine in your ubuntu.`
`2 - install game from wine.`
`3 - play your games.`

install wine `full`.
install good graphic driver.
install microsoft c++ and other software lije diretX with `wine` for `wine` for game:)!
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/